# chart cannot read multiple datasets from the back-end (single data is fine)

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using Angular 4, Chart.js 2.8.0 and ng2-charts 1.6.0 to create charts in my webpage. I have inserted the path to the chart.min.js (scripts section) in the angular-cli file and also imported ChartsModule in the app.module.ts file.

I first created the chart with the static data like below which worked fine (after constructor and before ngOnInit):

ts file

```
....
public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {data: [1,2,3,4,5], 
      label: 'Data 1'},
    {data: [5,6,7,8,9], label: 'Data 2'}
  ];
....
```

html file

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then, I tried to give it the back-end datasets (arrays of numbers: exmple: [11,12,13,14,15]). I had one called which was read after the ngOnInit:

```
this.test2 = this.tests.testResults;
```

I used the single data input like below and it worked fine:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="display: block" *ngIf="test2.length">
      <canvas baseChart
              [data]="test2"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But as soon as I want to make it two datasets in the ts file like below, it gives an error of "data not defined".

ts file (notice test 2 is [11,12,13,14,15])

```
....
public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {data: this.test2, 
      label: 'Data 1'},
    {data: [5,6,7,8,9], label: 'Data 2'}
  ];
....
```

html file

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="display: block" *ngIf="barChartData.length">
      <canvas baseChart
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the solution. Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/424). I defined my variable as below (this solved all the errors I mentioned above):

```
private test2: any[] = [{ data: [] }];
```

also, I changes the location of calling the `barChartData`.

First, in export class:

```
public barChartData;
```

then, inside my function that calls the backend data:

```
this.barChartData = [
            {data: this.test2, label: 'Data 1'},
            {data: this.test3, label: 'Data 2'}
          ];
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting data dynamically so you need to make an update on change. You will need `ChangeDetectorRef` for this. Do the following steps:

1) Add this in your imports:

`import { ChangeDetectorRef }  from '@angular/core';`

2) Add this in the constructor:

`private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef`

3) After changing the data do this:

`this.cdRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: Thank you  Orestis, I am still getting the same error of data not defined here: `ERROR TypeError: "newElm.data is undefined"
    datasets charts.js:123
    getDatasets charts.js:117
    getChartBuilder charts.js:57
    refresh charts.js:139
    ngOnInit charts.js:28
    Angular 5
    View_TestComponent_3 TestComponent.html:324
    Angular 27
    RxJS 5
    Angular 8
TestComponent.html:324:6`

Comment: Also, used this tutorial [https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/] but no success up to now! the same error!

Comment: What kind of variable is `newElm.data`? The input to provide must be an array. Meaning that either `newElm=[1,2,3,4,5]` or `newElm.data=[1,2,3,4,5]`. Try `console.log(newElm)` to see what the variable holds

Comment: This is strange! I don't have any newElm variable! So, when I try `console.log` doesn't recognise newElm!

Comment: Make sure the valiable you are using as input for the chart data to be an array. Let me know!

Comment: Yes, they are arrays. I mentioned in my question that the chart is printed with one data _test2_. This shows it is an array. But as soon as I group _test2_ with another array of static data (again in my question), I get the error of data is not defined. Do yo u have any idea where NewElm is coming from? I thought it is an abbreviation for **new element**.

Comment: Ok, you can try setting variables for the data of the chart like this
`public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {data: this.test1, 
      label: 'Data 1'},
    {data: this.test2, label: 'Data 2'}
  ];`
and then change the value of these variables and then check for changes